# How do I get Chicken of the VNC to connect to a port less than 5900?

Tags: mac-osx, vnc

According to the Chicken of the VNC documentation, it automatically adds 5900 to the indicated display number to calculate the port number to connect to.  (So I've been able to connect to port 5999 of a host by entering 99 as the display number.)  But I need to connect to a port less than 5900 at a particular host.  How do I do this?

Comment: I scoured for the preferences file for this application but cannot find it. This may be hard-coded. Look for another VNC viewer perhaps?

Comment: Not hard-coded, just (AFAIK) undocumented :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `:port` to the hostname (you'll notice the `Display` option box greys out when you do this), and Chicken of the VNC will use your specified port number rather than attempting to determine one based on the Display number.

Comment: I took a [look at the source code for the upcoming 2.0 release](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cotvnc/files/cotvnc/) and it is not possible to go below port 5900 if you use the dialog box for the display number. It is hard coded to add 5900 to any value you supply there.

Comment: Even if you use the colon Ian?  Or does the colon trick not work with 2.0?

Comment: Use a `:port` when entering a hostname and leave the display number blank.